# Is there an internal notion of "flat continuous presheaf"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

I have asked a version of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378965/is-there-an-internal-notion-of-continuous-flat-presheaf), but have been unable to receive an answer or devise one of my own, and am venturing that it may be appropriate for Math Overflow.

The "internal form" of Diaconescu's theorem (e.g. *Sketches of an Elephant* B3.2.7) tells us that for any topos $\mathcal{S}$, category $\mathbf{C}$ internal to $\mathcal{S}$, and $\mathcal{S}$-topos $p:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{S}$, there is an equivalence of categories $$\mathfrak{Top}/\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{S}^{\mathbf{C}^{op}})\simeq\mathbf{Flat}(\mathbf{C},\mathcal{E}),$$ the latter being the category of internal diagrams on $p^*(\mathbf{C})$ for which the internal category of elements is co-filtered (here using the convention where co-filtered means every finite diagram has a cone over it). Among Grothendieck toposes (with $\mathcal{S}=\mathbf{Set}$), we can further say that for a site $(\mathbf{C},J)$,
$$\mathfrak{Top}/\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{E},\mathbf{Sh}(\mathbf{C},J))\simeq\mathbf{ConFlat}((\mathbf{C},J),\mathcal{E}),$$ where the latter is the full subcategory of $\mathbf{Flat}(\mathbf{C},\mathcal{E})$ of flat functors that are continuous in the sense of taking covering sieves to colimiting cones.

### **The Question**

Suppose instead we're back to an arbitrary $\mathcal{S}$, and we're given a Lawvere-Tierney topology on $\mathcal{S}^{\mathbf{C}^{op}}$. Is there a notion of "internal continuity" so that the category of $j$-sheaves on $\mathcal{S}^{\mathbf{C}^{op}}$ classifies "internally continuous" flat diagrams on $p^*(\mathbf{C})$? If there is not such a condition generally, are there known to be any restrictions on $\mathcal{E}$ that make it work (such as boundedness over $\mathcal{S}$ or some such)?

Comment: I think you should be able to just rewrite the Set-based definition and proof in the internal language of $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: @MikeShulman - I think this gets to the heart of why I can't see my way through to the definition: I need to take the colimit in $\mathcal{E}$ in spite of the language of my covering sieves being that of $\mathcal{S}$. And I haven't been able to persuade myself that a geometric morphism would preserve covering sieves in a way that would let me use $p^*(\mathbf{C})$ directly in the language of $\mathcal{E}$ (unless $p^*$ happened to be logical). I'm sure there's something I'm not seeing.

Comment: The family of covering sieves is just a family of cones in $C$, which can be expressed diagrammatically in terms of a family indexed over $C_1\times I$ in $S$.  Applying $p^*$ gives an indexed family of cones in $p^* C$, and you should then be able to say in $E$ that these are colimiting in some internal diagram on $p^*(C)$.

Comment: Oh crud, you're right. I was thinking about it all wrong. I'll go ahead and write up my own answer when I get some time. Thanks!